# O que significa float("NaN") e float("inf") no Python?

Tags: python, float

Já vi um código assim:

```
def _min(*args):
    res = float('inf')
    for value in args:
        if value < res:
            res = value
    return res
```

Gostaria de saber o que é um `float("inf")` e um `float("NaN")`.

Comment: **inf** de infinito e **NaN** de não é um número. É essas as dicas que dou. (Dicas porque respostas absolutas não existem comigo :D )

Comment: O primeiro cria um número infinito, o segundo cria um número que não é um número "Not a Number". Tipo o resultado de "0.0/0.0", ou "inf - inf"

Comment: Obrigado ajudaram demais

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Infinito

Como já comentado, `float("inf")` vai criar um número infinito:

```
>>> float("inf")
inf
```

Que é na verdade equivalente a `math.inf`:

```
>>> import math
>>> math.inf
inf
>>> float("inf") == math.inf
True
```

Tem também a contraparte de -infinito:

```
>>> float("-inf")
-inf
>>> -float("inf")
-inf
```

É importante realçar que qualquer número é menor que infinito, assim como qualquer número é maior que -infinito.

Existe também um função em `math` para saber se é infinito, que se chama [isinf](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.isinf)

```
>>> math.isinf(float("inf"))
True
>>> math.isinf(float("-inf"))
True
>>> math.isinf(3421)
False
```

### NaN

`NaN` significa *Not a Number* que quer dizer que não é um número. Tem algumas formas diferentes de chegar a este valor. Uma delas é a que viu com `float("NaN")`:

```
>>> float("NaN")
nan
```

Outra seria subtraindo infinito a infinito:

```
>>> float("inf") - float("inf")
nan
```

Qualquer operação aritmetica sobre um `nan` irá dar na mesma um `nan`:

```
>>> float("nan") * 5
nan
```

Também tem a função [`isnan`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.isnan) que testa se é `nan`:

```
>>> math.isnan(float("nan"))
True
>>> math.isnan(25)
False
```

Leitura adicional de `inf - inf`:

- ["What is the result of ∞−∞?" no Stack Exchange de Matemática(em inglês)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60766/what-is-the-result-of-infty-infty)
- [Página da Wikipedia com as operações não definidas nas quais infinito-infinito é uma delas](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opera%C3%A7%C3%B5es_aritm%C3%A9ticas_com_infinito)

Comment: Haja alguém com iniciativa (;

Comment: math.inf só funciona do Python3 pra cima

Answer (score 5):

Só para completar a resposta do Isac que não comentou diretamente sobre o trecho de código da pergunta (que não é exatamente o foco, mas é interessante também saber), em funções que determinam o máximo ou mínimo de uma sequência de números há duas abordagens bem comuns:

1. Iniciar uma variável de controle com um valor conhecido e atualizá-la conforme verifica-se os valores da sequência. Considerando a função que determina o mínimo, você inicia a variável com esse valor conhecido e, se um determinado valor da sequência for inferior ao valor atual de controle, este passa a ser o novo valor. O problema consiste em garantir que o valor conhecido que é iniciado a variável seja maior que qualquer possível entrada da sequência, para que o mínimo seja, de fato, um valor da sequência. Se você iniciar a variável com 9999, por exemplo, funcionária para qualquer sequência que possui uma entrada menor que este valor, mas se for uma sequência de distância, em km, das estrelas na nossa galáxia, o resultado estaria errado. Assim, iniciando a variável como infinito, você contorna o problema, pois ele, por definição, é maior que qualquer valor numérico (vide código da pergunta). Para a função de máximo, acontece o contrário, tendo que possuir um valor menor que qualquer entrada, sendo iniciada em infinito negativo;
2. A outra abordagem é iniciar a variável com um valor não numérico, `None`, por exemplo, e no primeiro valor da sequência verificar que se for este valor não numérico, atribuir o primeiro valor da sequência a ele. Assim também é garantido que o resultado pertence à  sequência;

Exemplo:

```
def _min(*args): 
    res = None
    for value in args: 
        if res is None or value < res: 
            res = value 
    return res
```